# Append multiple Javascript variables onto a URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink, anchor

I'm attempting to output a link from a page of a site back to the linking site.

`invoiceNo` & `rawPrice` are variables that are extracted from the page prior to this and values extracted and converted to the appropriate string and float values.

If I hard code values in `(invoice001)` and `(29.99)`, for example, the script runs fine. However, as it stands all that happens is the variable name being displayed in the link.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.invoiceData = $('h2').text();
window.invoiceNo = invoiceData.substr(14);
window.priceBeforeCurrencyStrip = $('td.priceCol.balance').text();
window.price = parseFloat(priceBeforeCurrencyStrip.match(/[0-9.]+/));
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" 
        src="https://.......&SaleID='+invoiceNo+'&OrderVal='+price'">
</script>
```

Comment: Show us what you've tried.

Comment: Learn [ask] a question on StackOverflow

Answer (score 1):

This should fix your problem, your main problem was with quotes and scopes

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var invoiceData = $('h2').text();
    var invoiceNo = invoiceData.substr(14);
    var priceBeforeCurrencyStrip = $('td.priceCol.balance').text();
    var price = parseFloat(priceBeforeCurrencyStrip.match(/[0-9.]+/));
    var url = "www.google.com/test.js"

    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.setAttribute("src","http://"+url+"&SaleID="+invoiceNo+"&OrderVal="+price);
    script.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body");
    body.appendChild(script);
</script>
```

Comment: Sincerely, I've never seen this. So I went and tried it myself, and all I got was a invalid request to the invalid URL `https://url%26saleid%3D/`, and the following message in my Chrome Dev Tools:
`(failed) net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`

Comment: That's because you need to change the `url` bit to be the url of the script you want

Comment: Afraid not, looking at the page source it's now showing as a broken link and the 2 variables are still displaying as just the variable names.

Comment: The point is, I've never heard of JS variables laying around side by side with the <script> attributes. That doesn't seem valid HTML or JS to me.

Comment: My bad, I went full stupid....  Fixed it so it dynamically loads a script